# Probability of vertically polarized photon passing through a polarizing lens at an angle of 60∘ degrees from horizontal

Tags: quantum-mechanics, photons

Textbook says if a photon has vertical polarization.  When it hits the polarizing lens making an angle of 60∘ with the horizontal, the likelihood that the photon passes through is 75%.  How is 75% calculated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Light is a vector because it's an oscillating electric field and an electric field has a direction as well as a magnitude. What a polariser does is split the vector into a component parallel to the polariser and a component perpendicular to the polariser, then it allows the parallel component through and blocks the perpendicular component.

[image]

The diagram on the left shows the setup decribed in the question. The light vector is vertical and the polariser is at 60° to the horizontal. I think it's easier to rotate everything 30° counter clockwise to give the diagram on the right, because now we can easily see how the light splits into components parallel and perpendicular to the polariser.

Hopefully the diagram on the right makes it obvious how much of the light makes it through the polariser. If the originl electric field vector is $E$ then the component parallel to the polariser is $E\cos30°$ so the fraction of the vector making it through is $\cos30°$ and $\cos30° = \sqrt{3}/2$.

The last thing you need to know is that the probability of finding the photon is proportional to the vector squared, so in this case the probability is:

$$ P = (\cos30°)^2 = \left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\right)^2 = \frac34 = 75\% $$

Answer (score 0):

The probability is calculated cosine squared theta) or cos2theta.
Theta would be the angle of 60°.
In other words the cosine of 60° is .5. If you square .5 it is .5×.5 which equals .25. Another example would be the cosine of 45° is .707 and .707×.707 equals .5 or 1/2.
I think you are talking about 30° because the cosine of 30° is .866 and squared it would be 75%.